# upload video to Youtube from Laravel where the video isn't locally stored

Tags: php, laravel, video, youtube-api

I'm using Vimeo Pro as the hosting platform for our video content.

Our Laravel app then references the video source file in the database and our content curators add meta data to the videos.

When that's done, I'm looking for some way to post the video and its meta data to Youtube.

Unfortunately, it seems to be that the Youtube library isn't able to grab the video directly from a URL like so:

```php
$video = Youtube::upload('https://player.vimeo.com/external/533693191.hd.mp4', [
            'title' => 'Test Video',
            'description' => 'Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet rump turkey spare ribs shank, hamburger boudin frankfurter ham hock pancetta salami. Jerky porchetta salami, fatback swine chicken pastrami beef ribs landjaeger biltong. Capicola prosciutto leberkas landjaeger.'
        ]);
```

Is there a way around this or am I going to need to download the file first and then upload?

Comment: YouTube Data API does not allow uploading a video from a remote location (identified by e.g. an URL). By no means.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the Library it has to do with how HTTP Uploads are preformed. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2387